# Fluent Nhibernate - Mapping child in parent when Child has reference to parent and not using a list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a child object in the database that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Child
(
ChildId  uniqueidentifier not null,
ParentId uniqueidentifier not null
)
```

An then I have a parent like so.

```
CREATE TABLE Parent
(
ParentId uniqueidentifier not null
)
```

Now, the problem is that in my Parent class, I have

```
public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
```

I don't want to use a list if possible.  I know I could use a hasmany to a list and then just select the top 1 from the list in my Parent.Child property.

I've tried references, hasone, referencesany and can't seem to get the mapping right.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to use a list, and then Child property just grabs the first one in the list.  Not idea, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I model this type of relationship as one-to-many where the many side is restricted to n elements (in this case n=1). I model the many side as a private collection on the parent and restrict the number of elements through the property. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208796/modeling-one-to-zero-or-one-relationships-z-cardinality).